# Changing of MySQL ConnectionString does not have effect on PimCore project and it keep loading from older database

Tags: pimcore

I have created a PIMCore project and at the time of pimcore-install command I have used database name 'X', after sometimes, I did change connection string and point to 'Y' database on the same server having same schema but with some data.
But the problem that i am facing is that it keeps loading and login in the project/admin panel using old db 'X' users. Please guide me what steps I should take so that it will point to new database 'Y' and get logged in with database 'Y' users.

I have tried with following steps after change of connection string
`php bin/console cache:clear`
`php bin/console pimcore:cache:clear`

But it still loading from old. Please guide me what I have to do to achieve desired result

Comment: I believe it is good to see your Database.yml here. Do you have only 1 PHP server?  https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues/5936 https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Pimcore/Deployment/Deployment_Tools/